# Two databases to one linked table on SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, linked-tables

We have an Access database that is currently doing an append query on a table on another database. We have moved all the tables to a SQL Server 2008 database.

The dba used the SSMA tool to migrate the tables to the SQL Server database thus avoiding the use of an ODBC connection. If necessary I could write VBA code to create the link (I have seen an example that I might be able to use).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Found some VBA code that will allow me to create the linked table.